# 本文中の URL に日本語が含まれる場合、プレビュー時はデコードされるのに閲覧時はエンコーディングされた状態で表示される

Tags: バグ

本文中に貼り付けた URL に日本語が含まれる場合、閲覧表示中はパーセントエンコーディングされた状態で表示されますが、なぜかプレビュー表示中のみデコードされて表示されます。

以前は常にエンコーディングされていたような気もしますが、記憶に自信がありません。
できれば日本語が読める状態で表示されてくれた方が嬉しいです。

**閲覧表示:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**プレビュー表示:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**確認環境:**
Windows 10
Firefox 80.0, Chrome 85.0, Opera 70.0

Comment: 補足: [スクリーンショット元の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/70020/32986)