# リストとコードブロックを併用するとリストがプレビューでしか機能しないケースがある

Tags: バグ, サポート, markdown

### 不具合事象

リストとコードブロックを併用したとき、プレビューではリストとして動作しているものの、実際にはリストになっていないケースがありました。この挙動は[質問・回答・スニペットのマークアップ練習場](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3438/32986)で確認しました。

たとえば、次のような Markdown ではリスト番号 1, 2 のどちらもリスト要素になります。この動作はプレビューと実際の結果で一致しています。

````
1. 
```
text
```
2.
```
text
```
````

次に、以下のようにリスト番号 1 の直前にテキストを挿入した場合、プレビューではこれらはリストとして機能しています。しかし、実際の結果ではリスト番号 1 がリストとして機能していませんでした。プレビューと実際の結果のどちらが正しい結果でしょうか？

````
テキスト

1. 
```
text
```
2.
```
text
```
````

### 再現環境

- Google Chrome 87.0.4280.66
- Opera 72.0.3815.320

Answer (score 0):

閲覧時とプレビュー時で結果が異なる挙動は [他にもある](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3405) のでバグの可能性がありますが、それとは別に今回の場合、リスト記法で `1.` の **後に何も文字列が無いのが原因** な気がします。

以下のように適当な文字列を記述して投稿を保存すれば、「リスト番号1」も正常にリストとして表示されます。

**Markdown:**

````
テキスト

1. aaa
```
text
```
````

**表示結果:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、[CommonMark への切り替え案内](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3348) にも例が示してある通り、リスト記法に段落を含める場合には、適切なインデントが必要です。正しくは以下のように記述する必要があります。

**Markdown:**

````
テキスト

1. aaa
   ```
   text
   ```
2. bbb
   ```
   text
   ```
````

**表示結果:**

テキスト

1. aaa

   ```
   text
   ```
2. bbb

   ```
   text
   ```